# Migrating from one neo4j database in one ec2 machine to neo4j database in other ec-2 machine having different versions

Tags: linux, database, amazon-ec2, neo4j, graph-databases

I am having some data stored in my ec2 machine having neo4j version 3.5.. , I want to migrate that to another ec2 machine having neo4j version 4.1. What would be the best stratetgy to do that ?
Both machines having linux installed on them, and is it possible to migrate only a part of the data ? I am completely new to programming in general, apologies if the doubt is trivial .

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use neo4j-admin dump and neo4j-admin load on the target

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/

you might need to configure the upgrade database flag in the /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.allow_upgrade